# How to access vue JS global property in setup method

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vue-composition-api

I am using [nuxt GTM](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@nuxtjs/gtm) module to track events for GTM.

Per the document, I can easily access gtm object using `this.$gtm`.

I am having trouble using the same object in the Vue JS setup method of composition API. I have tried exploring context param of setup method, there I can see $gtm under parent but its greyed out and I cannot access the same. Attached image for the same[image]

Answer (score 0):

Docs says :

Since in Vue 3, the setup method doesn't have access to this.$gtag but you can import the method you need like this

```
import { event } from 'vue-gtag'

export default {
  name: 'MyComponent',

  setup() {
    const login = () => {
      event('login', { method: 'Google' })
    }
    
    return {
      login
    }
  }
}
```

[source](https://matteo-gabriele.gitbook.io/vue-gtag/#:%7E:text=%7D-,Since%20in%20Vue%203%2C%20the%20setup%20method%20doesn%27t%20have%20access%20to,%7D,-Initial%20config%20parameters)